# Call an asyncron php script on a Linux Server

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

I try to execute a `.php` script with the `shell_exec()` function on a 1&1 Linux shared Webserver (debian GNU/Linux 8 distribution).

```
    private function callAsyncSkript(){
    // Asynchron Zipping over executing a Script in a new process.
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        $cmd = "start /B php .\src\Core\Services\AsynchronZip.php fileids=".$this->idQuery . " fulllink=".$this->uri;
        pclose(popen($cmd, "r"));
    }
    else {

        $cmd = "/usr/bin/php7.2-cli ".getcwd()."/src/Core/Services/AsynchronZip.php fileids=".$this->idQuery . " fulllink=".$this->uri;
        shell_exec("/usr/bin/nohup ".$cmd." >/dev/null 2>&1 &"." | at now");
        //shell_exec("/usr/bin/nohup ".$cmd." >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
    }
}
```

The "/usr/bin/nohup " addition don´t help to execute the script asynchron,
if iam using " | at now" the script will not be executed. 
Are there some special settings i have to set or are there other options for an asynchron execution over the commandline?

I found out that the only shell available to me is a rssh. Is it possible that she is the mistake.

Comment: what version of linux are you running? For ubuntu this command should work:
 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &

Comment: It is a debian GNU/Linux 8 distribution.

Comment: looks like the command to run something in the background in debian distribution is here: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/user/ch6.html using: $cmd . ' bg' might do it...

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but without success. My Script call looks like shell_exec($cmd." bg"); I read in the link you sent bg is only a synonyme for &. The "()" isnt working too (The "()" is for starting a sub-shell).

Comment: Does the script run at all? I believe there's a config setting in PHP.ini that restricts/allows shell access

Comment: yea it is running synchrone.